# asp.net 4 navigation

Tags: asp.net

Hello i just deployed my web site to the remote server. I noticed that the menu (navigation) bar is doesn't display as on my local server. I am using visual studio 2010.
The stylesheet was also deployed to my remote server. I am using the new asp.net 4 already designed navigation. It works find on my local machine but not on the remote machine. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use `firebug` (a firefox) extension to make sure that you are using the correct CSS classes for the menu, as it is in the development version. Check the CSS files exist on the server. I guess it may be a path problem (wrong path to the CSS file). Use the "Net" tab in firebug to see whether the files are present on the server or not.

Are you getting the same problem in some particular browser ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure correct version of all files are uploaded.
2. Next, check the .NET version set for the application on the server.